# searching a jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, search, datatables

I am using jquery datatables 1.10 and trying to search and filter a table. I would like to use a search text box that searches two columns and a check box to filter the results of a third column. Here is my datatable:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("SupportClass1Search", "SupportClass1")';
$('#SupportClass1DataTable').DataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
    "processing": true,
    "ajax": url,
    "ordering": true,
    "dom": '<"top"prl<"clear">>t<"bottom">pi<"clear">',
    "pageLength": 10,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "columns": [
        { // create a link column using the value of the column as the link text
            "data": "SupportClass1Id",
            "width": "20%",
            "render": function (oObj) { return "<a href='#' onclick='editItem(\"" + oObj + "\")'>" + oObj + "</a>"; },
        },
        { "data": "SupportClass1Name", "sWidth": "70%" },
        { // convert boolean values to Yes/No
            "data": "Active",
            "width": "7%",
            "render": function (data, type, full) {
                if (data == true)
                { return 'Yes'; }
                else
                { return 'No'; }
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

I want to filter the 3rd column (Active) based on a checkbox value. The JS below works to filter the table but is not picking up the Active column when I enter "Yes" or "No":

```
// use an outside search input
oTable = $('#SupportClass1DataTable').DataTable();

$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
    oTable.search($('#txtSearch').val()).draw();
})
```

Also, I would prefer to search the Active column separately, kind of like this:

```
oTable
    .column(2).search('Yes')
    .columns([0,1]).search($('#txtSearch').val())
    .draw();
```

but this doesn't work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: you can check my yadcf filter for datatables , it have 9 different filter types with integration with other third party plugins http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/ https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Using version 1.10 you have to use ajax.data:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

In my initialization, I used the following to add an extra parameter to my ajax call:

```
"ajax": {
    "url": url,
    "data": function (d) {
        d.activeOnly = $('#activeOnly').is(':checked');
    }
},
```

Here is my full initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // initialize the data table
    var url = '@Url.Action("SupportClass1Search", "SupportClass1")';
    $('#SupportClass1DataTable').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": url,
        "ordering": true,
        "dom": '<"top"prl<"clear">>t<"bottom">pi<"clear">',
        "pageLength": 10,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": url,
            "data": function (d) {
                d.activeOnly = $('#activeOnly').is(':checked');
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            { // create a link column using the value of the column as the link text
                "data": "SupportClass1Id",
                "width": "20%",
                "render": function (oObj) { return "<a href='#' onclick='editItem(\"" + oObj + "\")'>" + oObj + "</a>"; },
            },
            { "data": "SupportClass1Name", "sWidth": "70%" },
            { // convert boolean values to Yes/No
                "data": "Active",
                "width": "7%",
                "render": function (data, type, full) {
                    if (data == true)
                    { return 'Yes'; }
                    else
                    { return 'No'; }
                }
            }
        ]
    })

    oTable = $('#SupportClass1DataTable').DataTable();

    // this is a checkbox outside the datatable 
    // whose value I wanted to pass back to my controller

    $('#activeOnly').click(function () {
        oTable.search($('#txtSearch').val()).draw();
    })

    $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
        oTable.search($('#txtSearch').val()).draw();
    })
});
```

I am using a class as a model for the DataTable. I added the activeOnly parameter/property here also:

```
/// <summary>
/// this class provides a model to use with JQuery DataTables plugin
/// </summary>
public class jQueryDataTableParamModel
{
    #region DataTable specific properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Request sequence number sent by DataTable,
    /// same value must be returned in response
    /// </summary>       
    public string draw { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of records that should be shown in table
    /// </summary>
    public int length { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// First record that should be shown(used for paging)
    /// </summary>
    public int start { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Custom properties

    public bool activeOnly { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult SupportClass1Search(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
{
    // initialize the datatable from the HTTP request
    var searchString = Request["search[value]"];
    var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["order[0][column]"]);
    var sortDirection = Request["order[0][dir]"]; // asc or desc

    // query the database and output to a viewmodel
    var lvm = new SupportClass1SearchViewModel { };
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        lvm.SupportClass1List = supportClass1Service.GetAll();
    }
    else
    {
        lvm.SupportClass1List = supportClass1Service.FindBy(t => (t.SupportClass1Name.Contains(searchString))
            && (t.Active.Equals(param.activeOnly) || param.activeOnly == false));
    }

    // do a bunch of stuff and retunr a json string of the data
    return MyJson;
}
```

Now, when I click on the activeOnly checkbox and it redraws the table passing true or false to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the columnfilter plugin http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html ( a jQuery Datatables plugin) as it can do much of what you are seeking.   Here is an example in [jsFiddle Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/e91wkLc2/).  In this example I am using 2 fields for text filtering and the 3rd is a dropdown

```
    oTable = $("#myTable").dataTable({
    bInfo: false,
    bSort: false,
    bSortable: false,
        "data": arrayData,
        "columns": [{
        "data": "Emp"
    }, {
        "data": "Name"
    }, {
        "data": "Role"
    }, {
        "data": "Notes"
    }]
}).columnFilter({
    sPlaceHolder : "head:before",
    aoColumns : [{
        type : "text"
    }, {
        type : "text"
    }, {
        type : "select",
        values : arrayRoles
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this work with DataTables version 1.10? It looks like your syntax is 1.9

Comment: Yes, works with latest version.   The datatable is 1.10.2 that is references in the jsFiddle.   1.10 has both the older structure (objects) as well as the newer structures (API) (the little "d" vs the BIG "D" )

Comment: Here is a URL example using the API version on their site https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html that may also help

Comment: what's odd is I can't even get the column search to work on one column: $('#btnSearch').click(function () { oTable.columns(1).search($('#txtSearch').val()).draw(); })