# mdbootstrap pagination basic table load data according to page number

Tags: jquery, html-table, pagination, loading

I'm using mdboostrap pagination basic table. link: [enter link description here](http://%20https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/pagination/)https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/pagination/
1) How can i load only one page data from server according with page number.(Also show how many total number of items are there). 
2) Search problem. In case I'll load only one page data, how can i give searched text to server side  and callback searched items to load in table.

Comment: If the mdbootstrap theme uses this [datatables plugin](https://datatables.net/), then you can solve it like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585602/searching-a-jquery-datatables) or you find all informations about it [here](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've posted their official site and answer is : "Hi. I'm afraid not.The problem is that datatables dynamically sets the number of pages. For example: if you set 10 lines to appear on one page and download 100 records, then pagination will show 10 pages. But if you only want to download 10 records, how do you simulate that 10 pages should appear? I don't see option in docs to manually set how many pages should be available."